# SQL Server merges elements in XML, but should be separate elements

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sqlxml, for-xml-path

I have the following query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 'St. Kulakow 12' AS 'address',
             'P123' AS 'address'
FROM tab
FOR XML PATH ('ROOT')
```

It returns me merged tag 'address', but it should be separate.

I get:

```
<ROOT>
  <address>St. Kulakow 12P123</address>
</ROOT>
```

but should be:

```
<ROOT>
 <address>St. Kulakow 12</address>
 <address>P123</address>
</ROOT>
```

Is there any option to get it separate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do:

```
SELECT TOP 1 'St. Kulakow 12' AS 'address',
             NULL,
             'P123' AS 'address'
--FROM tab
FOR XML PATH ('ROOT')
```

or

```
SELECT TOP 1 'St. Kulakow 12' AS 'address',
             '',
             'P123' AS 'address'
--FROM tab
FOR XML PATH ('ROOT')
```

The "empty element" serves as a sort of breaker for the elements.

Answer (score 2):

TT. you were right :)
But in below case it will not work at all:

```
SELECT 'Warsaw' AS 'ADR/City',
       'WKPL' AS 'ADR/State',
       'St. Kulakow 12' AS 'ADR/address',
        NULL,
       'P123' AS 'ADR/address',
       '12345' AS 'ADR/Zip'
FOR XML PATH ('ROOT')
```

You will get:

```
<ROOT>
  <ADR>
    <City>Warsaw</City>
    <State>WKPL</State>
    <address>St. Kulakow 12</address>
  </ADR>
  <ADR>
    <address>P123</address>
    <Zip>12345</Zip>
  </ADR>
</ROOT>
```

So we need to add alias to your solution:

```
SELECT 'Warsaw' AS 'ADR/City',
       'WKPL' AS 'ADR/State',
       'St. Kulakow 12' AS 'ADR/address',
        NULL AS 'ADR',
       'P123' AS 'ADR/address',
       '12345' AS 'ADR/Zip'
FOR XML PATH ('ROOT')
```

And then we will get:

```
<ROOT>
  <ADR>
    <City>Warsaw</City>
    <State>WKPL</State>
    <address>St. Kulakow 12</address>
    <address>P123</address>
    <Zip>12345</Zip>
  </ADR>
</ROOT>
```

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

Table Name: DemoAddress

```
Id | Address
------------
1  | aaaa
2  | bbbb
3  | cccc
```

The query will be like this

```
select 'address'=Address from DemoAddress FOR XML PATH (''),type,root('root')
```

And Then we get

```
<root>
  <address> aaaa</address>
  <address> bbbb</address>
  <address> cccc</address>
</root>
```